# Error while deployment of Gitlab on OpenShift pipeline

Tags: openshift

I am trying to deploy Gitlab source code OpenShift. But I am facing an issue. Though in Gitlab pipeline it is successful. It keeps talking about the unauthorized error.

My expected output is to have deployment on OpenShift [Error message] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBBzO.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the Deployment Pod is unable to pull the specified image.

It appears your Deployment is in the namespace `roks-test-demo-project` while the image your are trying to pull is in the `oc-custom-dev` namespace. In order for a Deployment in one namespace to pull an image from another, the Deployment's service account must be authorized to do so.

See the [OpenShift documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/openshift_images/managing_images/using-image-pull-secrets.html#images-allow-pods-to-reference-images-across-projects_using-image-pull-secrets) for how to achieve this.

In your case, assuming your Deployment is running as the `default` service account:

```
$ oc policy add-role-to-user \
    system:image-puller system:serviceaccount:roks-test-demo-project:default \
    --namespace=oc-custom-dev
```

If your Deployment is running as a non-default service account, replace `default` with that service account name in the above command.